# Tips on appraising items

Tags: dragons-crown

Dragon's Crown have a lot of things to make you spend your money on, like Buy items and equipment, as well as appraising, repairing and reviving allies.

Therefore are there any tips to not get poor by over spending your gold in appraising?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[redd530 posted](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/632915-dragons-crown/66909208) some useful tips for appraising I really liked:

> - **??~???** reflects what damage range you'll get. In this case, 2 question marks means a 2 digit number while 3 means a 3 digit number (eg. 41~165). This means that **???~???** is better than **??~???**
> - **?????** means that you'll get a *bonus stat*.
> - **??????????????** means you'll get a *bonus effect*.
> - Some lower ranked items are actually useful. But usually keep ranks S, A, B, and C. Ranks D and E are almost always useless.
> - Don't bother keeping items with no bonus effects.